# solve this question by refering image attached

Tags: numerical-optimization

[please refer to question in picture form it is on topic numerical differenciation and integeration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S9l2.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Indeed, please [don’t use 
images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem) instead of [typing your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Moreover, look at [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) and [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).